# Move data from multiple rows to a single row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as show below-

```
F1  F2  F3  F4  
A   AB  NA  NA  
A   NA  BC  NA  
A   NA  NA  CD  
B   UV  NA  NA  
B   NA  WX  NA  
B   NA  NA  YZ  
C   ABC NA  NA  
C   NA  BCD NA  
C   NA  NA  XYZ
```

I need to group by column F1 and choose values for consecutive columns not equal to 'NA'.

```
F1  F2  F3  F4  
A   AB  BC  CD  
B   UV  WX  YZ  
C   ABC BCD XYZ
```

I am using the following code but it is not working correctly.

```
 SELECT   F1
,MAX(ISNULL(F2 ,'')) as F2   
,MAX(ISNULL(F3 ,'')) as F3   
,MAX(ISNULL(F4 ,'')) as F4   
     FROM test
     group by F1;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT   F1
,MAX(ISNULL(NULLIF(F2, 'NA') ,'')) as F2   
,MAX(ISNULL(NULLIF(F3, 'NA') ,'')) as F3   
,MAX(ISNULL(NULLIF(F4, 'NA') ,'')) as F4   
     FROM test
     group by F1;
```

Note that the NULLIF will return NULL if the value of the first parameter is the same as the value of the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT F1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN F2 = 'NA' THEN '' ELSE F2 END) AS F2
    MAX(CASE WHEN F3 = 'NA' THEN '' ELSE F3 END) AS F2
    MAX(CASE WHEN F4 = 'NA' THEN '' ELSE F4 END) AS F2
FROM test
GROUP BY F1;